# Using collection_singular_ids=ids vs update_attributes(:collection_ids)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, save

why does

```
@thing.tag_ids = params[:thing][:tag_ids]
```

save the relation at once in the database, but

```
@thing.update_attributes(params[:thing][:tag_ids])
```

does not if the validation fails?

```
@thing.update_attributes(params[:thing][:tag_ids])
```

is the same as

```
@thing.tag_ids = params[:thing][:tag_ids]
@thing.save
```

isn't it?

Comment: How does `update_attribute` know to update `tag_ids`? I think you have some errors there.

Comment: `update_attributes` expect one or more key/value pairs. You only have value input, no key.

Answer (score 1):

You are *kinda* correct, the following two statements are the exact same:

```
# save
@thing.key = value
@thing.save

# update
@thing.update_attributes({key: value})
```

---

The issue with your code is that you have a syntax problem, you want:

```
@thing.update_attributes({tag_ids: params[:thing][:tag_ids]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution it seems that the first method is using update_attribute for updating single attribute and hence validations are never executed. But in case of update_attributes as we know validations are always executed

Read more here:- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute

Comment: Yes but the above two comments are also correct you must have intentionally or by mistake dropped the tag_ids from @thing.update_attributes({tag_ids: params[:thing][:tag_ids]}). Because without this your program must have given error

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling with such behaviour...

Code:

```
@thing.tag_ids = params[:thing][:tag_ids]
```

makes changes in DB ad hoc and it does not invoke validations so:

```
@thing.update_attributes(params[:thing][:tag_ids])
```

is different than

```
@thing.tag_ids = params[:thing][:tag_ids]
@thing.save
```

In short:

```
@thing.tag_ids = params[:thing][:tag_ids] # makes changes in DB w/o validations
@thing.save # runs validations before making changes to DB
```

I'm also asking if there is possibility to run validations when using:

```
@instance.collection_singular_ids = other_singular_ids
```

As a quick fix I added override method to parent model (the 'thing') like so:

```
def tag_ids=(ids)
  super
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  self.errors.add(:base, e.message)
end
```

and validator to prevent duplication of tags in join model like so:

```
validates :tag_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :thing_id}
```

Does anyone have a better fix?